# How to add a new column stating "weekday" or "weekend" using lubridate?

Tags: r, lubridate, mutate

I have a bunch of dates in year-month-date format , trying to add a new column in the data frame that states if the date is a "weekday" or a "weekend" (either or).

I have to use mutate and lubridate. Tried using wday but not sure how to specify. Outcome should be something like the following:

date                    weekend_weekday
2023-02-15                  weekday

How to format this in the code and which function to use?

Comment: https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/day.html has everything you need to define weekday vs weekend day.  After that the mutate is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lubridate::wday()` and check if the date is `1` (Sunday) or `7` (Saturday):

```r
library(dplyr)

dat <- tibble(id = 1:7,
              Date = Sys.Date() + id)

dat %>% 
  mutate(weekend = ifelse(wday(Date) %in% c(1,7), "weekend", "weekday"))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>      id Date       weekend
#>   <int> <date>     <chr>  
#> 1     1 2023-02-17 weekday
#> 2     2 2023-02-18 weekend
#> 3     3 2023-02-19 weekend
#> 4     4 2023-02-20 weekday
#> 5     5 2023-02-21 weekday
#> 6     6 2023-02-22 weekday
#> 7     7 2023-02-23 weekday
```

To be safe and not rely on the system options we should specify the `week_start` argument. If we set it to `1` the week starts at Monday, and we need to check if a date is `6` (Saturday)  or `7` (Sunday):

```r
dat %>% 
  mutate(weekend = ifelse(wday(Date, week_start = 1) >= 6,
                          "weekend", "weekday"))

#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>      id Date       weekend
#>   <int> <date>     <chr>  
#> 1     1 2023-02-17 weekday
#> 2     2 2023-02-18 weekend
#> 3     3 2023-02-19 weekend
#> 4     4 2023-02-20 weekday
#> 5     5 2023-02-21 weekday
#> 6     6 2023-02-22 weekday
#> 7     7 2023-02-23 weekday
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>